# store MySQL server fetched data in android app while no connection available`

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I had created a android app those data updates from MySQL server when connection is available, Now I need to store previously fetched data in app  and update them if new data is available. my data size is not more than 1 MB, which will the best solution  Sqlite or SharedPreferences?

Answer (score -1):

Use Sqlite data base,
if you want to secure db , then you can look into sql-lite chipper.